# Is there an ISO C compliant way to make a function that returns a pointer to a function nested inside?

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int (*function_factory(int outer_args))(int){ 
    int returned_function (int inner_args){ 
        return outer_args + inner_args;     
    }
    return &returned_function;
}

int main(void){                
    printf("%d\n",function_factory(1)(2)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

When I try to compile the above code with the -pedantic and -Werror flags, I get the error `error: ISO C forbids nested functions`. For the purposes of my task, assume I can't remove those two flags. Is there a way I can return a function that will take inner_args while still having access to outer_args?

Comment: No. The reason is, and this might come as a surprise, that "ISO C forbids nested functions". :)

Comment: Ah well, I had hope there was a way to bypass that limitation through a clever shortcut I had no knowledge of.

Comment: The closest thing you can do is save the outer argument in a global/static variable that the inner function can access, but that's horribly non-reentrant (=thread unsafe).

Comment: Yeah, I'm not touching global variables with a 3.048 m pole, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Title seems confusing, of course you can use function pointers -- but not nested functions

Comment: Note also that the flags are not really the core problem.  The nested function is.  A few C compilers do support nested functions as an extension, but in no way is that portable.  You would do well to learn standard C before you move on to compiler-specific extended dialects.

Comment: Removing the flags won't help. Although GCC supports nested functions, they are "downward funargs" only and not full lexical closures; you cannot return them and safely use them. Your code will compile, but bomb.

Comment: Is there an ISO-C way to support GNU extensions? No, fortunately...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although GNU C does support nested functions, it will not work anyway. Nested functions in GNU C are "downward funarg only". They are not lexical closures; everything is on the stack. When the parent of a nested function terminates, that function becomes garbage; using the returned function pointer outside of that scope is not well-defined.

(GNU C local functions also require an executable stack. They fit the downward closure into a regular C function pointer, which requires the construction of piece of machine code on the stack called a "trampoline".)

To simulate lexical closures in standard C, you have to hoist all the function bodies to file scope (no nesting) and use an explicit closure data structure which holds a pointer to the code and to the captured environment:

```
#include <stddef.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct counting_closure {
  /* simulated captured environment */
  int count;
  /* pointer to code */
  int (*lambda)(struct counting_closure *);
};

int counting_lambda(struct counting_closure *clo)
{
   /* simulated access to captured lexical */
   return clo->count++;
}

struct counting_closure *make_counter(int start)
{
   struct counting_closure *clo = malloc(sizeof *clo);
   clo->count = start;
   clo->lambda = counting_lambda;
   return clo;
}

int main(void)
{
   struct counting_closure *cntr = make_counter(1);
   printf("%d\n", cntr->lambda(cntr));
   printf("%d\n", cntr->lambda(cntr));
   printf("%d\n", cntr->lambda(cntr));
   free(cntr);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have nested functions but you can return a function pointer:

```
typedef int (*FuncPtr)(void);

int sample(void){
    return 1;
}

FuncPtr choose(int f)
{
    if (f == 1) return sample;
    return NULL;
}

main()
{
    FunPtr p = choose(1);
    if (p) { printf("%d\n", p()); }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realize my question was not well asked, you answered what I did ask perfectly though. Thank you!
Unfortunately, what I meant was a little different and does not seem possible.

Comment: Suggest you either edit your title to be the actual question or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

No. The C language does not have nested functions, and even the "GNU C" extension for them does not allow you to call them after the enclosing function invocation has ended.

The correct and portable way to do this is in C is with a pair (possibly stored in a struct, if you like) of function pointer and pointer to struct containing the context. The context can then be allocated on the stack of the "enclosing function invocation" if you won't use the context after the invocation ends; otherwise, it can live in allocated storage (`malloc`) which you explicitly free when done with it.

Such a pair cannot be passed to interfaces which only take a function pointer, but good APIs using function pointers also take a (usually `void *`) context argument to be passed back to the function.